# Problems with Xamarin's GridLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
 <Grid
                                Margin="30,30,30,30"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorBack002}"
                                RowSpacing="40">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>



                                <!--#region Method Name-->
                                <Label x:Name="xTxtMethod"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                                    Text="Name" />


                                <Ctrl:CtrlTextEdit x:Name="xEditMethodname"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    BoxHeight="70"
                                    Margin="0,0,15,0"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    Style="{StaticResource TextEditStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding MethodName}" />
                                <!--#endregion-->
```

I have a layout like this. I set TextEdit's HorizontalOption to FillAndExpand.
On screen, the tip of TextEdit is cut off by about 1 pixel. Why does this happen?

Textedit seems to be expanded to fit the screen, but it seems to have expanded beyond that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc8OG.png)

Comment: Are you sure this is not an issue with your custom control?

Comment: Could you provide some relevant code about your `Ctrl:CtrlTextEdit` so that I can reproduce the situation you described.